# Как подружить Twig и Handlebars?

Tags: symfony2, twig, handlebars

Есть шаблон-заготовка:

```
<script id="short-url" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{% raw %}
<div class="short-url">
    <div class="url" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="{{ url }}" data-url="{{ url }}">
        {{ url }}
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="{{ url }}"
           target="_blank" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Go to the link">
           <i class="im-link"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="hlink-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="{{ url }}" 
           data-placement="top" data-toggle="clipboard" data-original-title="Copy the link">
           <i class="im-copy"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ single_page_url }}" 
           target="_blank" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Complete report for the page">
           <i class="im-stats"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ report_in_url }}" 
           target="_blank" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="The Inbound Links Report URL">
           <i class="im-arrow-down-left2"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ report_out_url }}"
           target="_blank" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="The Outbound Links Report URL">
           <i class="im-arrow-up-right3"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endraw %}
```

Все здорово в этой заготовке, но еще нужно переводить предложения через Translation (сейчас они захардкожены)... но в этом случает Twig начинает конфликтовать с Handlebars. Поясню мою идею: хочется статичные элементы отрисовать сразу (при рендеренге страницы), а динамические части прорисовать позже JavaScript'ом при переборе JSON-массивчика.

К прмеру:

```
<a href="{{ url }}"
   target="_blank" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="{{- table.go_to_link|trans -}}">
   <i class="im-link"></i>
</a>
```

А при рендеренге страницы `data-original-title="{{- table.go_to_link|trans -}}">` должно замениться на нужное предложение.

Возможно ли это сделать? Каким образом?

Answer (score 2):

1. данный вопрос решался [по этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces), но там был применен angular. Если быть кратким, то "{{" были заменены на "{[{", может быть в вашем js фреймворке можно сделать то же самое?
2. Так же, вы можете убрать {%raw%} и для отрисовки шаблонов для js'а воспользоваться хитростью: `<a href="{{ '{{url}}' }}"`, тогда все останется нативным у twig и у handlebars

Comment: Большое спасибо. Второе решение отлично сработало для меня.
Первое тоже хорошее, даже лучше чем первое, но мне неудобного его внедрить на текущей момент в проекте.

Comment: @МихаилЩедраков был рад помочь